# How to run code before flutter app is shutdown?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there any possibility to run code before a Flutter app is shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html with https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html

I think `suspending` is the closed and to my experience it is also called before the app is killed.